# Refresh component after database update in Angular 5

Tags: angular, components, refresh

I have a parent component with route /home which contains a list and when a list item is clicked, I navigate to /home/edit/listid and update the database. After the database update, I am navigating back to /home. But the list is not updated until I refresh the page manually. 
I also tried calling dataservice.getList() after updating the database, but no luck.
Below is my code. Can someone please help me identify what I am missing?

**Home Component**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadList();
  }
  loadList() {
    this.dataservice.getList().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.List= res;
      },
      err => {
        console.log('Error Occoured');
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

**DataService getList()**

```
getList(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.post<any[]>('https://resturl/Prod/getdata', {
      'operation': 'getData'
      }
    });
  }
```

**Edit List**

```
this.dataservice.updateList().subscribe(
        updateAccRes => {
            this.dataservice.getList();
            this.router.navigate(['/home']);
          }
        },
        error2 => {
          console.log(error2);
        }
      );
```

Comment: I cannot see something wrong here. The `ngOnInit` should be called when you are routing back (make sure the `getList()` method is called). But I'm wondering why you are getting the list from your API with a `post`

Comment: probably you are navigated to /home before the service finished and you don't have any mechanism to update parent component. (your new data is fetched but never passed to parent component try to use Subject/BehaviorSubject to communicate b/w component/service and redirect to home after list is been fetched.

Comment: That cannot be the reason. He doesn't have to call `getList()` in the Edit List Component, because he is not subscribing to it. So it doesn't do anything. When he routes back to home in the subscribe of `updateList` (the call finished) he should route back to home and `getList` should be called in the `ngOnInit` of the Home Component. Here he is updating the list

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript's asyn is your problem. When you navigate to Home, the response of updated list has not came back yet, so you have to manually reload the page. A solution for this is to have a common variable in service which can be accessed by both components and *ngIf in your Home Component's HTML to check for updates in the common variable.

**Edit List** 
You just need to update items here. The navigation should be called inside this.dataservice.getList() to make sure it wait for the response from the getList() call.

```
this.dataservice.updateList().subscribe(
    updateAccRes => {
        this.dataservice.getList();
      }
    },
    error2 => {
      console.log(error2);
    }
  );
```

**DataService getList()** Create a common variable here, update it with the response from getList(), and then navigate to **/home**

```
latestList: any;
getList(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.post<any[]>('https://resturl/Prod/getdata', 
        {'operation': 'getData'})
        .subscribe(response => {
             this.latestList = response.list;
             this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
        }
)};
```

**Home Component** Now, after updated list comes back, we are navigated to **home page**, and the updated list is ready to be displayed without manually reload the page.

```
listOfItems: any
constructure(private dataService : DataService){
    // latestList is accessible here because it is a property of DataService
    this.listOfItems = this.dataService.latestList;
};
```

**home.component.html** You can check for the updated list's existence here. If it exists, show it. If it does not exist, show "loading...." message.

```
<div class="list" *ngIf="listOfItems"> <!-- Display list here --> </div>
<div *ngIf="!listOfItems"> Loading.......... </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a service that holds the item list,
And in your edit-list-component, you'll update the item in the service.
That way, you'll have the same item both in main component and in edit-list-component.

Example:

```
class ItemsService{ 
   list: Items[]; 

   getItemById(index){
       return list[index];
   } 
   updateItemById(item, index){
       this.list[index] = item;
   }
}


class EditListComponent{
   item:Item;
   index:number;
   ...
   this.item = this.itemsService.getItemById(index);

   updateBtnClick(){
         this.itemsService.updateItemById(item, index);
   }
}
```